# Adding items to array doesn't seem to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have written a function that adds a ball to an array yet when I check the count it hasnt increased, please can someone advise.

```
NSMutableArray *_otherBalls;


-(void)addBall{
    CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"redbouncyball.gif" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)]; 

    [self addChild:target];

    //add to our array
    [_otherBalls addObject:target];

    NSLog(@"Added ball : %@",[_otherBalls count]);
}
```

The log comes out as

> Added ball : (null)

Comment: `_otherBalls.count` ? did you mean `[_otherBalls count]` ?

Comment: Ah yes, woops, still get (null) though

Comment: Perhaps it works, but it's still wrong. `count` is not declared as a property and you shouldn't use it as such.

Comment: Don't use single leading underscores on your variable names.  That's an Apple internal coding convention, and they do it so that their names won't collide with yours.

Comment: Oh really? I was doing that from tutorials that I read! Ill bear that in mind next time, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code it seams that you have never initialized the array. So it' cant store anything. Unless you did in init, but thats hard to guess.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 NSLog(@"Added ball : %lu",[_otherBalls count]);
```

count is an integer, not an NSObject.

Comment: Actually, it should be `%lu`.

Comment: This is correct, but not the problem... as 0 is semantically the same as nil here.

Answer (score 1):

Is `_otherBalls` an `NSMutableArray`? Did you make sure to `alloc` and `init` `_otherBalls`?

**EDITED:** to reflect edited question

Comment: Yes it is, I updated the code (and the Q) with the correct count syntax and still get the issue

Comment: Ahh spot on, silly mistake.  Why didnt XCode crash or throw an exception when I tried to add an item to an uninitialized array?

Comment: it is legal (won't cause an exception) to send a message to nil.  Quite different from most other languages

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Added ball: %d", [_otherBalls count]);
```

Try this because you are counting objects in an array and the result would be integer.

If the problem persists then it means that you havent initialized your array

```
_otherBalls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```